# UWP with Node.js and C# library. How to debug the C# side?

Tags: c#, node.js, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windowsiot

I have a problem with my application for Raspberry PI with Windows IoT Core. I would expose a little server to manage the IO. For do that, I've a C# library that manage the IO and a WinRT bridge to take the informations from the C# library and give them to the Node.js server. But when I put a breackpoint in the C# library or in the WinRT bridge, it does not work. It only works in the Node.js file.
How could I manage it? There's a way to make it works?
Thanx a lot for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expose a little server to manage the IO.

Enables Node.js to use the [ChakraCore JavaScript engine](https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore) you full [access to UWP APIs from Node.js applications](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/05/12/bringing-node-js-to-windows-10-iot-core/#ADMT8WCFPtsV1rsW.97). No need for C# library and WinRT bridge.

[HelloBlinky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloblinkybackgroundnode) is official sample of managing GPIO in Node.js server that you can reference.

Comment: Thanx Rita, but is a little bit more complex than I've exposed. I Really need to debug the C# side because I have an infrastructure that manages a lot of entities and I want to expose through RPi the status of my sensors net. Really... I need to debug the C# side, not implement the GPIO management in JS.
Thanx

Comment: @DarioBenevento How is your project organization?

Comment: Hi Rita, to make it simply: I have a project in C# that manage messages from external sensors through a gateway via WebSoket. The structure is a mapping of sensor hierarchy, building hierarchy and a mapping between them with some logic of management. Approximately 200k lines of code. In this scenatio i would expose a webpage that represents the schema. 
I've found how insert a bridge between Node.js and Universal Application but I can't debug the C# side.

Comment: Do you use [visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)? What kind of bridge do you use, [Bridge.NET](http://bridge.net/) ? How does your edge work? Do you mind showing your code?

Comment: Hello Rita, excuse me for my late.
1) I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
2) The bridge (as I sayd before) is a WinRT component (Visual Studio template for it)
3) Don't be mad about my code or something like that. Try to create a Node.js project, add a WinRT component in the same solution and put it as reference in the Node.js project. Now try to call a WinRT class method from Node.js and... enjoy! The breackpoint does not work.

Now: if you have any idea is welcome, otherwise let's stop here.

Thanx a lot for support